# Sort part of array with heapsort, bug

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, heapsort

Here is my code for a introsort. I have trouble getting the heapsort part of the code working.

`partition()` and `sort()` works like it should, but the heapsort part doesnt sort correctly. I get sorted arrays (size=10) like this:

```
10
18
26
35
25
39
49
49
57
89
```

There are mostly sorted, except for a few numbers. I am only trying to sort a part of the array in each `heapsort()` call.

```
public class IntroSort {

    public static void sort(int[] arrayToSort){     
        int depth = ((int) Math.log(arrayToSort.length))*2;
        sort(arrayToSort, depth, 0, arrayToSort.length-1);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] arrayToSort, int depth, int start, int end){
        int length = arrayToSort.length;
        if(length <= 1){
            return;
        }else if(depth == 0){
            heapSort(arrayToSort, start, end);
        }else{
            if(start >= end)
                return;
            int pivot = arrayToSort[(start + end)/2];
            int index =  partition(arrayToSort, start, end, pivot);
            sort(arrayToSort, depth-1, start, index-1);
            sort(arrayToSort, depth-1, index, end);
        }
    }

    private static void heapSort(int[] arrayToSort, int start, int end){
        for (int i = end / 2 - 1; i >= start; i--)
            heapify(arrayToSort, end, i);
        for (int i=end-1; i>=start; i--){
            int temp = arrayToSort[start];
            arrayToSort[start] = arrayToSort[i];
            arrayToSort[i] = temp;
            heapify(arrayToSort, i, start);
        }
    }

    private static void heapify(int[] arrayToSort, int n, int i){
        int largest = i;
        int l = 2*i + 1;
        int r = 2*i + 2;
        if (l < n && arrayToSort[l] > arrayToSort[largest])
            largest = l;
        if (r < n && arrayToSort[r] > arrayToSort[largest])
            largest = r;
        if (largest != i){
            int swap = arrayToSort[i];
            arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[largest];
            arrayToSort[largest] = swap;
            heapify(arrayToSort, n, largest);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] arrayToSort, int start, int end, int pivot){
        while(start <= end){
            while(arrayToSort[start] < pivot){
                start++;
            }
            while(arrayToSort[end] > pivot){
                end--;
            }
            if(start <= end){
                int temp = arrayToSort[start];
                arrayToSort[start] = arrayToSort[end];
                arrayToSort[end] = temp;
                start++;
                end--;
            }
        }
        return start;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Carlton, 
i ran your code on some arrays, and data in that arrays had been sorted.
Can you give examples, where your algorithms didn't work correct.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{17,1,15,1,2,3,18,100,100,454};
    heapSort(arr, 0, arr.length);
    for (int i:arr)
        System.out.print(i+" ");
```

and in result i got:

```
1 1 2 3 15 17 18 100 100 454
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: It goes wrong when you try to sort just a part of the array, like you call `heapSort(arr, 3, 6)`

Answer (score 1):

Because your `heapify` method can not build a max-heap for just a **portion** of the input array.

Let's have a look at an example: consider you have an array of length 10 and you want to sort the portion from 3 to 6, you'll call `heapSort(array, 3, 6)`, from your code:

```
private static void heapSort(int[] arrayToSort, int start, int end){
    for (int i = end / 2 - 1; i >= start; i--)
        heapify(arrayToSort, end, i);
    for (int i=end-1; i>=start; i--){
        int temp = arrayToSort[start];
        arrayToSort[start] = arrayToSort[i];
        arrayToSort[i] = temp;
        heapify(arrayToSort, i, start);
    }
}
```

It'll call `heapify(array, 6, 2)` in the first for loop at first step, then in your `heapify` implementation, you'll compare the `2nd` element with the `5th` and `6th` element and even maybe swap it with one of the later two. So the `2nd` element involved unexpected when you want to sort portion 3 to 6, and even maybe swapped with `5th` or `6th` element, which makes the result incorrect.

If you want to build a `portionHeapSort`, I think it could be better to build a `heapSort` firstly, then build `portionHeapSort` based on it like the code below:

```
private static void portionHeapSort(int[] arrayToSort, int start, int end) {
    // start and end both inclusive
    int[] subArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSort, start, end + 1);
    heapSort(subArray);
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        arrayToSort[i] = subArray[i - start];
    }
}
```

Hope this could be helpful to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a code solving just that.
[Here's a link to my post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115008/iterative-in-place-sub-list-heap-sort-python-implementation/56126048#56126048)

I'll also paste the code here for simplicity:

```
def buildMaxHeap(arr, arrayLength, indexStart, attr):
    for i in range(arrayLength):

        # if child is bigger than parent
        if getattr(arr[indexStart + i], attr) > getattr(arr[indexStart + int((i - 1) / 2)], attr):
            j = i

            # swap child and parent until
            # parent is smaller
            while getattr(arr[indexStart + j], attr) > getattr(arr[indexStart + int((j - 1) / 2)], attr):
                (arr[indexStart + j],
                 arr[indexStart + int((j - 1) / 2)]) = (arr[indexStart + int((j - 1) / 2)], arr[indexStart + j])
                j = int((j - 1) / 2)


def heapSort(arr, arrayLength, indexStart, attr):
    buildMaxHeap(arr, arrayLength, indexStart, attr)

    for i in range(arrayLength - 1, 0, -1):

        # swap value of first indexed
        # with last indexed
        arr[indexStart + 0], arr[indexStart + i] = arr[indexStart + i], arr[indexStart + 0]

        # maintaining heap property
        # after each swapping
        j, index = 0, 0

        while True:
            index = 2 * j + 1

            # if left child is smaller than
            # right child point index variable
            # to right child
            if (index < (i - 1) and getattr(arr[indexStart + index], attr) < getattr(arr[indexStart + index + 1], attr)):
                index += 1

            # if parent is smaller than child
            # then swapping parent with child
            # having higher value
            if index < i and getattr(arr[indexStart + j], attr) < getattr(arr[indexStart + index], attr):
                arr[indexStart + j], arr[indexStart + index] = arr[indexStart + index], arr[indexStart + j]

            j = index
            if index >= i:
                break
```